# whats the difference between these 2 for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop

I currently have this multi-dimensional list and I am trying to extract the first column from it:

```
>>> print(data)
[['com.borderstylo.retrollect', '0', '0'], ['aabasoft.presents.goldprice', '0', '0'], ['aberl.vlc.light.mote', '0', '0']]
```

when I use

```
sitelist = [] 
for row in data:
    sitelist.append(row[0])
print(sitelist)
```

I get the output below, which is what i am after.

```
['com.borderstylo.retrollect', 'aabasoft.presents.goldprice', 'aberl.vlc.light.mote']
```

However, when i use

```
sitelist = []
sitelist = (row[0] for row in data)
print(sitelist)
type(sitelist)
```

I get the output below instead, which is a generator object.  What is a generator object and why does the 1st set of code return something different from the 2nd? both appear very similar.

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x001A9E10>
generator
```

Many thanks for replies.  Newbie at python but really wanting to learn.

Comment: List comprehensions use brackets, not parentheses. Parentheses make a genexp.

Comment: You may be interested in [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python). The parentheses make a generator comprehension, not a list comprehension (which uses brackets).

Comment: `sitelist = [row[0] for row in data]`

Comment: The difference is they are not two for loops, only the first one is. The keywords you should search for are 'generator expression' and 'list comprehension'.

Comment: I see!  Thanks so much for all the replies. This makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions in python are created using `[]`.
As an alternative, when dealing with very large data, you can construct a generator using the same syntax as with comprehensions, only with `()`.

Thus, just change `()` with `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

`row[0] for row in data` gives a generator object. This is like lazy evaluation. It means this for loop does not get executed to produce the result, instead a generator object is created which can be used to execute the for loop one iteration at a time when and if required.
This is done for efficiency in terms of time and memory.

When this is enclosed in parenthesis, `sitelist = (row[0] for row in data)` is treated as in expression and the resulting generator object is stored (referenced) in `sitelist`.

When this is enclosed in square brackets, `sitelist = [row[0] for row in data]` it is a list comprehension. The for loop is executed  right away and a list is constructed and stored (referenced) in `sitelist`.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259) for more information on iteration protocol in python.
Then explore generators in python. There many articles/blog posts which explain generator with varying level of details.